# Имитация работы банкомата при выдаче денег

Tags: php

Код принимает  сумму денег и колличество купюр,которые в нем есть  и выводит наиболее легкий способ выдачи (для него) купюр,показывает сколько купюр нужно выдать и каких. Помогите,пожалуйста,добрые люди добавить в код возможность анализа,чтобы не перебирать все возможные вариант, например:
Число банкнот: 1 по 5000, 4 по 2000, 1 по 500, 3 по 200  выдать: 6600 р.
В МОЕЙ программе он зацепит 5000 сразу и скажет "а шо це таке",а должен пропустить 5000 и сделать 3 раза по 2000...

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html ; charset=utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<?php
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');


function Bank($summ)
{
$massiv=array_fill(0,1,5000);
$massiv1=array_fill(0,2,1000);
$massiv2=array_fill(0,6,500);
$massiv3=array_fill(0,2,100);
$massiv4=array_fill(0,25,50);
$massiv5=array_fill(0,50,10);
$massivkol=array();



    if (($summ/5000)<=(count($massiv))){ 
       $summm=floor($summ/5000); 
        $summ-=($summm*5000); 
        $massivkol[0]=$summm; 
    }
    else 
        {
        $summm=($summ/5000)-(count($massiv)); 
        $summ-=(count($massiv)*5000);
        $massivkol[0]=(count($massiv)); 
    }

    if ($summ/1000<=count($massiv1)){
        echo "$summ";
        $summm=floor($summ/1000);
        echo "$summm";
        $summ-=($summm*1000);

        $massivkol[1]=$summm;
    }

    else 
        {

        $summm=($summ/1000)-(count($massiv1));
        echo "$summm <br>";
        $summ-=(count($massiv1)*1000);
        $massivkol[1]=(count($massiv1));
    }

    if ($summ/500<=count($massiv2)){
        $summm=floor($summ/500);
        $summ-=($summm*500);
        $massivkol[2]=$summm;
    }

    else 
        {
        $summm=($summ/500)-(count($massiv2));
        echo "$summm <br>";
        $summ-=(count($massiv2)*500);
        $massivkol[2]=(count($massiv2));
    }

    if ($summ/100<=count($massiv3)){
        $summm=floor($summ/100);
        $summ-=($summm*100);
        $massivkol[3]=$summm;
    }
    else 
        {
        $summm=($summ/100)-(count($massiv3));
        echo "$summm <br>";
        $summ-=(count($massiv3)*100);
        $massivkol[3]=(count($massiv3));
    }

    if ($summ/50<=count($massiv4)){
        $summm=floor($summ/50);
        $summ-=($summm*50);
        $massivkol[4]=$summm;
    }

    else 
        {
        $summm=($summ/50)-(count($massiv4));
        echo "$summm <br>";
        $summ-=(count($massiv4)*50);
        $massivkol[4]=(count($massiv4));
    }

    if ($summ/10<=count($massiv4)){
        $summm=floor($summ/10);
        $summ-=($summm*10);
        $massivkol[5]=$summm;
    }

    else 
        {
        $summm=($summ/10)-(count($massiv5));
        echo "$summm <br>";
        $summ-=(count($massiv5)*10);
        $massivkol[5]=(count($massiv5));
    }






    if ($summ==0)
    {
    return $massivkol;
    }
else {
    echo "Нет достаточного колличества купюр.";
}
}
$summ=3200;
//$summ=mt_rand(1,99999);
$massivchik=array();
if($summ%10==0){
$massivchik=Bank($summ);
echo "<br>Сумма денег: $summ <br>
Колличество 5000 купюр: $massivchik[0] <br>
Колличество 1000 купюр: $massivchik[1]<br>
Колличество 500 купюр: $massivchik[2]<br>
Колличество 100 купюр: $massivchik[3]<br>
Колличество 50 купюр: $massivchik[4]<br>
Колличество 10 купюр: $massivchik[5]<br>

   ";
}
else {
    echo "<br>Сумма денег: $summ <br>Сумма не кратна 10,деньги выдать невозможно";
}
```

Comment: В МОЕЙ программе он зацепит 5000 сразу и скажет "а шо це таке",а должен пропустить 5000 и сделать 3 раза по 2000... - ну значит в вашей программе все правильно. Почему по 2000 должен сумму 6600 выдать? Что бы потом, если кому то нужно бует 2000 не сработать? По логике банкомат должен выдавать максимально возможный номинал, пока он не кончится.

Comment: В слове "количество" одна буква "л".

Comment: спасибо, ЧСВ ответ по существу от ЧСВ существа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно немного упростить от делать нечего -

```
 $cassette = [5000 => 3, 2000 => 6, 500 => 2]; // кассета - номинал купюры и количество (можно изменить приоритет выдачи путем изменения порядка следования в массиве)

 function Bank($summ)
 {
      global  $cassette;
      $notes = []; // купюры на выдачу
      $_cassette = $cassette; // делаем временную кассету
      foreach($_cassette as $nominal => $count) { // перебираем все купюры
           while( ( $_cassette[$nominal] > 0 ) && ($sum >= $nominal) ) { // пока у нас сумма больше чем номинал текущей купюры и пока у нас эти купюры есть в кассете
                 $_cassette[$nominal]--; // забираем купюру из кассеты
                 $sum -= $nominal; // отнимаем номинал выданной купюры от суммы
                 $notes[] = $nominal; // добавляем купюру на выдачу
           }
           if($sum == 0) { // если выдали всю сумму можно дальше не смотреть номиналы купюр
               $cassette = $_cassette; // изменяем кассету
               return $notes; // возвращаем массив выданных купюр
           }
      }
      return false; // иначе ничего не получилось
 }
```

Это конечно можно сильно улучшить.